# Executor framework future.get() hangs

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code that runs a process and I want to know if there was an exception while running it. It hangs for no reason

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = runtime.exec(command.toString());
ProcessHandler errorStream = new ProcessHandler(proc.getErrorStream(),"ERROR", rdyFilePath);
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future future = pool.submit(errorStream);
pool.shutdown();

try {
     if(future.get() == null) {
         log.info("Done completing error thread");
     }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the class for process handler

```
public class ProcessHandler implements Callable<Integer> {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProcessHandler.class.getName());

    InputStream inpStr;
    String strType;
    String rdyFile;


    public ProcessHandler(InputStream inpStr, String strType, String rdyFile) {
        this.inpStr = inpStr;
        this.strType = strType;
        this.rdyFile = rdyFile;
    }

    public Integer call() throws FileMetadataException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {

            InputStreamReader inpStrd = new InputStreamReader(inpStr);
            BufferedReader buffRd = new BufferedReader(inpStrd);
            String line = null;
            while((line = buffRd.readLine()) != null) {
                if("ERROR".equalsIgnoreCase(strType)) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    log.info(strType + "->" + line);
                }
            }
            if(sb != null) {
                log.info("Error Stream length : " + sb.length());
                throw new RuntimeException();

            }

            buffRd.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException in ProcessHandler Thread" + e.fillInStackTrace());
            System.err.println(e);
            throw new FileMetadataException();
        } finally {
            if(sb != null) {
                if(sb.toString().length() > 0 ) {
                    log.error("Error string buffer length " + sb.length());
                    // do not create rdy file
                } else {
                    log.error("Error string buffer length : " + sb.length());
                    File f = new File(rdyFile);
                        try {
                            f.createNewFile();
                        } catch(IOException e) {
                            log.error("IOException while creating rdy file");
                        }
                    }
                    // create rdy file. 
                }
            }
            return sb.length();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When do you expect it to finish?  It's probably stuck at `while((line = buffRd.readLine()) != null) {`

Comment: `sb` is never going to be `null` in case their's any question.  Did you mean `sb.length() != 0` or maybe `line != null`?

Comment: Also, you certainly want to use `StringBuilder` and _not_ `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @John Vint: Yes it is stuck at that line. Can you please explain what the reason might be ?

Answer (score 2):

> I have the following code that runs a process and I want to know if there was an exception while running it. It hangs for no reason

If there was an exception your `future.get()` should have thrown with an `ExecutionException` -- it would not "hang".  Are you sure that your exception is not being printed but somehow lost in the logs or console output?

In tracing your code, I see no way for your program to not finish after it finishes reading the stream.  Maybe the process whose error-stream you are reading from is still running and the `InputStream` has not been closed yet?   Maybe there is so much output that you are filling up core with the `StringBuffer` (which should be changed to a `StringBuilder` btw).

Can you attach to your application with jconsole to see if the thread is still running and if it is, what is it doing?

```
 if(future.get() == null) {
     log.info("Done completing error thread");
 }
```

So this will only log output if you return `null` from your `call()` method.  That will never happen since the only return is `return sb.length();`.  So either you will get an exception from your `call()` or your result will be a non-null `Integer`.

Comment: Yes, it is not throwing any exception and I replaced StringBuffer with StringBuilder. I also replaced the if block with Object s = future.get(); but it still hangs.

Comment: Could the process that you are reading from still be running @user1707141?

Comment: @Gray, this is what I suspect. I've found when running external processes in Java that if you do not fully consume both the Standard out and Error streams, the process will never return, and thus would produce this hanging behavior that OP is referring to. Check out this https://opencast.jira.com/svn/MH/tags/1.0.1/modules/matterhorn-kernel/src/main/java/org/opencastproject/util/StreamHelper.java

Comment: You should post that as an answer @rmlan.

Answer (score 2):

From the `Process` javadoc:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

Per this warning, your `future.get()` method is hanging because you are only consuming the error stream from the process object. On all platforms I have ever utilized `Process` objects, I have observed that you need to consume both the Error and Standard out streams.

[This](https://opencast.jira.com/svn/MH/tags/1.0.1/modules/matterhorn-kernel/src/main/java/org/opencastproject/util/StreamHelper.java) is a good tool that uses a multithreaded approach to ensure that streams of a process are consumed.

In this case, since it appears that you don't care about the standard output of the process you might add something like this, borrowing the `StreamHelper` class:

```
StreamHelper inStreamHelper = new StreamHelper(proc.getInputStream());
inStreamHelper.start();
```